# Chrome Extension Rejected by Chrome Store

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My extension is rejected 3-4 times now. I have an extension which works with InboxSDk and adds an icon in the actions panel of the compose window. According to google this is the issue:

> We don't comments specifically on what cause issues with privacy exceptions but here are some generic comments that may help:

> TABS:
> Does not grant access to methods on the tabs API
> Does grant access to 4 properties on Tab instances
> ACTIVETAB:
> Does not grant access to tabs APIs or give passive access to the currently active tab
> Does grant temporary host permissions for a domain when the extension is invoked
> STORAGE:
> Does not grant access to the open web's localStorage or IndexedDB APIs
> Does grant access to chrome.storage APIs such as chrome.storage.local or chrome.storage.sync

> Please review the following links:
>
> ```
> developer.chrome.com/webstore/program_policies?csw=1#userdata
> developer.chrome.com/webstore/user_data
> developer.chrome.com/extensions/security
> ```
>
> Note that extensions should not run on all tabs when it is note invoked or be available to be invoked when it is not needed.

My manifest.json looks like this,

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "MY EXTENSION TITLE",
  "version": "1.1",
  "permissions": ["storage","activeTab"],
  "content_scripts" : [
    {
      "matches": ["https://mail.google.com/*", "https://inbox.google.com/*","*://*/*"],
      "js": ["js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js","js/vue.js","js/vuetify.js","js/axios.min.js","inboxsdk.js", "app.js"],
      "css": ["app.css"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["axios.min.js", "background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "icon.png",
    "app.css",
    "fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff2","fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff","fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf","fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf","fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot",
    "css/font-awesome.css","css/materialdesignicons.css","css/vuetify.min.css"
  ],
  "icons": {"128": "extension.png"}
}
```

[Screenshot of my answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opKLJ.png)

Comment: It's impossible to tell just by looking at manifest.json which permissions are necessary, but there's definitely no need for `"https://mail.google.com/*", "https://inbox.google.com/*"` because they are covered already by `"*://*/*"` and most likely there's no need for `activeTab` permission. It's also wrong that you inject app.css both via content_scripts and also list it in web_accessible_resources.

Comment: Hi, @wOxxOm thank you so much for the reply. I will remove the unnecessary code from the manifest as you described and then try again to publish. Could you please tell me what should be write in host permission field? I have attached a screenshot of the answers I am providing them. https://i.stack.imgur.com/opKLJ.png

Comment: You seem to understand that already but to clarify, host permission" means the sites that your extension is granted access to via `permissions` and `matches`. Hence, your extension wants access to all sites (`"*://*/*"`). In that field on your screenshot you need to provide an explanation why your extension needs that. Without seeing your code I can't say your explanation sounds convincing because access shouldn't be necessary to just open a tab.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm. Is there a way I can provide you access to my code and at the same time keep my code private?

Comment: No, StackOverflow doesn't work like that. You need to provide an [MCVE](/help/mcve) here so we can answer a question based on that alone.

Comment: @wOxxOm Oh!! Thanks for letting me know. I was not aware of that :( I have one more question as I am using InboxSDK.js, vue.js, vuetify.js. Do you think any of these scripts use any remote code? I have all of them in my local package. I have attached InboxSDK.js here so that you can view.

Comment: Vue should use only the code you load yourself explicitly. Dunno about vuetify or inboxsdk so you need to inspect their source code.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the help on this. I will try to change my code and will try to publish again on the store.